# How to use included Files in Executables Jar

Tags: javafx, jar, inputstream

I have the Problem, that my Application needs Images (jpgs), audio files (mp3) and css files. In the IDE I can just use a string to point to them and use them.

I have read how to include these files in the jar (with Project -> Properties -> Sources -> Add Folder).

Than I read one can use "getRessource()" or "getRessourceAsStream".

I tried to load the Images inside my jar with "getRessource()"...that didn't worked. So i tried getRessourceAsStream. That worked and I was able to create an JavaFx.Image from the InputStream. Code for that:

```
InputStream bild = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/eins.jpg");
Image img = new Image(bild);
```

Most of the answers from Questions "How to use Files inside a jar" say that you should always use the InputStream.

Now my Problem is that I use "scene.getStylesheets().add()" For that method I need a String not an InputStream. Same goes for "Media m = new Media()".

Either there is a way to Use the InputStream from both Ressources (to add css and audio file) or to convert the InputStream to something I can use for those 2 methods. Both is fine with me.

This Code doesnt work for me:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/style.css");
scene.getStylesheets().add(url.getFile());
```

So whats the way to use that included css file in my jar. If possible with InputStream it's fine with me, I dont need to use "getRessource".

Thanks for help! If some Information missing just tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: That worked for the css file! Thanks!!! What does the toExternalForm() exactly do? Or in what way is this method different from getFile(). Both are making a String from an URL or?

But that solution doesnt worked for the Media problem I edited the question, do you have a Solution for that?

Comment: `url.getFile()` returns only the path of the file e.g. C:\users\xyz\filename.css, while  `url.toExternalForm()`contains the protocol type e.g. file:C:\users\xyz\filename.css.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!